# how do i run a test with jest/RTL on authcontext()

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jestjs, passport.js, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the process of my code when the user logs in correct information; however, i get stuck on an error that states that authContext is seen as undefined. Am i testing this correctly? How do i fix this error?

error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'setUser' of undefined

      25 |           const { isAuthenticated, user } = data;
      26 |           if (isAuthenticated) {
    > 27 |             authContext.setUser(user);
```

loginForm.test.js

```
    test('user input correct login information', () => {
        const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<LoginForm />);
        const resInfo = {username: 'Bpun1p'}
        const resp = {isAuthenticated: true, user: resInfo}
        AuthService.login.mockResolvedValue(resp)

        fireEvent.change(getByTestId('Username'), {target: {value: "Bpun1p"}})
        fireEvent.change(getByTestId('Password'), {target: {value: "Guy123su"}})

        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('LoginBtn'));
    });
```

loginForm.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import SocialSignUp from './SocialSignUp';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';
import AuthService from '../../service/AuthService';

function LoginForm() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState({ username: '' });
  const [isValidEntry, setValidEntry] = useState(true);

  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const history = useHistory();

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setUsername({ ...username, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (username.username !== '') {
      AuthService.login(username)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          const { isAuthenticated, user } = data;
          if (isAuthenticated) {
            authContext.setUser(user);
            authContext.setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
            history.push('/profile/global');
          } else setValidEntry(false);
        });
    } else setValidEntry(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Test `<LoginForm/>` replace with  `<AuthContext.Provider> <LoginForm/><AuthContext.Provider>`
and pass the required props for AuthContext.Provider for the run app